After upgrade to .NET 8.0, I'm getting EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: "Could not save changes because the target table has database triggers"
I upgraded my ASP.NET Core 6 Web API to .NET 8.0.
At the Signin page, I have this code:
public async Task<IActionResult> LoginAttempt([Bind("Email","Password","PingIdPin","SelectDeviceMessage","SelectDevice","CollectPinMessage","CollectPin","MultipleDevices","MultipleDevicesYesNo","ChallengeId","UserPrompt","LoginFailed")] LoginModel loginModel)
{
    // more snippets of the code
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult result = new();

    try
    {
        result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, false, false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string ss = ex.Message;
        _logger.LogInformation(-999000001, "{0} ... result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, false, false); [{1}]", nameof(Login), ex.Message);
    }
}

I get this exception:

EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: 'Could not save changes because the target table has database triggers. Please configure your table accordingly, see https://aka.ms/efcore-docs-sqlserver-save-changes-and-output-clause for more information.'
SqlException: The target table 'AspNetUsers' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause.

I upgraded all the Nuget packages to 8.0.8 for Entity Framework Core.
Please see screenshot with the NugetPackages for 8.0
With .NET 6.0, it worked seamlessly. Not sure what am I missing when upgrading to .NET 8.0.

Edited this post to add my DBcontext.cs code
namespace AspNetCoreApi.Models.Identity
{
  public class AppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser<int>,
                                                                      ApplicationRole<int>,
                                                                      int,
                                                                      ApplicationUserClaim<int>,
                                                                      ApplicationUserRole<int>,
                                                                      ApplicationUserLogin<int>,
                                                                      ApplicationRoleClaim<int>,
                                                                      ApplicationUserToken<int>>
  {
      public AppIdentityDbContext() { }

      public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }
      public static int MessageMaxLength;

      public AppIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppIdentityDbContext> options)
          : base(options) { }

      protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
      {
          optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString);
          base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
      }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUsers>().ToTable(tb => tb.HasTrigger("TriggerName"));
            
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
             modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser<int>>(entity =>
             {
                 entity.ToTable(
                     "AspNetUsers");

                 entity.HasKey(x => x.Id);
                 entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedEmail)
                     .HasDatabaseName("EmailIndex");

                 entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedUserName)
                     .HasDatabaseName("UserNameIndex")
                     .IsUnique()
                     .HasFilter("([NormalizedUserName] IS NOT NULL)");

                 entity.Property(e => e.CreatedBy).HasMaxLength(50);

                 entity.Property(e => e.Email).HasMaxLength(128);

                 entity.Property(e => e.Facility).HasMaxLength(50);

                 entity.Property(e => e.FirstName).HasMaxLength(50);

                 entity.Property(e => e.LastName).HasMaxLength(50);

                 entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasMaxLength(128);

                 entity.Property(e => e.NormalizedEmail).HasMaxLength(128);

                 entity.Property(e => e.NormalizedUserName).HasMaxLength(128);

                 entity.Property(e => e.PhoneNumber).HasMaxLength(50);

                 entity.Property(e => e.UpdatedBy).HasMaxLength(50);

                 entity.Property(e => e.UserName).HasMaxLength(50);

                 entity
                     .HasMany(e => e.Claims)
                     .WithOne()
                     .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId);

                 entity
                     .HasMany(e => e.Tokens)
                     .WithOne()
                     .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId);

                 entity
                     .HasMany(e => e.Logins)
                     .WithOne()
                     .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId);

                 entity
                     .HasMany(e => e.Roles)
                     .WithOne()
                     .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId);                
                     
             });
        }
}

After adding "HasTrigger" line it doesn't show the error but doesn't do anything and stops the application. What am I doing wrong here?
Below is my generated SQL.
 public async Task<int> SaveUser(UserVM model, string thisUser)
 {
     bool hasErrors = false;
     int retUserId = 0;

     if (model.Id > 0)
     {
         AspNetUsers user = await (from u in _context.AspNetUsers
                                   where u.Id == model.Id
                                   select u).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

         user.Email = model.Email;
         user.NormalizedEmail = model.Email.ToUpper();
         user.FirstName = model.FirstName;
         user.MiddleName = model.MiddleName;
         user.LastName = model.LastName;
         user.Inactive = !model.Active;
         user.UserName = model.UserName;
         user.NormalizedUserName = model.UserName.ToUpper();
         user.Name = model.UserName;
         user.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
         user.UpdatedBy = thisUser;

         _context.AspNetUsers.Update(user);
         await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

         AspNetUserClaims claimLname = await (from c in _context.AspNetUserClaims
                                              where c.UserId == user.Id
                                              && c.ClaimType == "Surname"
                                              select c).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

         if (claimLname != null)
         {
             if (claimLname.ClaimValue != user.LastName)
             {
                 claimLname.ClaimValue = user.LastName;
                 _context.AspNetUserClaims.Update(claimLname);
                 await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
             }
         }

         AspNetUserClaims claimFname = await (from c in _context.AspNetUserClaims
                                              where c.UserId == user.Id
                                              && c.ClaimType == "GivenName"
                                              select c).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

         if (claimLname != null)
         {
             if (claimLname.ClaimValue != user.LastName)
             {
                 claimFname.ClaimValue = user.FirstName;
                 _context.AspNetUserClaims.Update(claimFname);
                 await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
             }
         }

         if (hasErrors == false)
         {
             var deleteRoles = await (
                 //_context.AspNetRoles.Where(x => EF.Property<int>(x, "UserId") == user.Id).ToListAsync());
                 _context.AspNetUserRoles.Where(x => x.UserId == user.Id).ToListAsync());

             foreach (var i in deleteRoles)
             {
                 _context.AspNetUserRoles.Remove(i);
                 try
                 {
                     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                     string s = ex.Message;
                 }
             }

             // remove claim for Role
             var userClaimRoles = await _context.AspNetUserClaims
                                 .Where(x => x.UserId == user.Id && x.ClaimType == "Role")
                                 .ToListAsync();

             foreach (AspNetUserClaims claim in userClaimRoles)
             {
                 _context.AspNetUserClaims.Remove(claim);
             }

             // remove claim for Name Identifier
             userClaimRoles = await _context.AspNetUserClaims
                                 .Where(x => x.UserId == user.Id && x.ClaimType == "NameIdentifier")
                                 .ToListAsync();

             foreach (AspNetUserClaims claim in userClaimRoles)
             {
                 _context.AspNetUserClaims.Remove(claim);
             }

             await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

             string roleName = await (from r in _context.AspNetRoles
                                      where r.Id == model.RoleId
                                      select r.RoleName).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

             var entity = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(user.Email);

             if (entity != null)
             {
                 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(roleName))
                 {
                     await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(entity, roleName);
                     await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(entity, new Claim("Role", roleName));
                 }

                 await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(entity, new Claim("NameIdentifier", user.UserName));

                 await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
             }

             // set if no errors otherwise return 0 which is error in page
             retUserId = user.Id;
         }
     }
     else
     {
         int newUserId = 0;

         ApplicationUser<int> entity = new ApplicationUser<int>
         {
             Id = model.Id,
             Email = model.Email,
             UserName = model.UserName,
             FirstName = model.FirstName,
             MiddleName = model.MiddleName,
             LastName = model.LastName,
             Name = model.UserName,
             NormalizedUserName = model.UserName.ToUpper(),
             NormalizedEmail = model.Email.ToUpper(),
             CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
             CreatedBy = thisUser,
             UpdateDate = DateTime.Now,
             UpdatedBy = thisUser,
             Inactive = !model.Active,
             SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
         };

         IdentityResult result
             = await _userManager.CreateAsync(entity, model.Password);

         if (result.Succeeded)
         {
             newUserId = entity.Id;

             await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(entity, new Claim("GivenName", entity.FirstName));
             await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(entity, new Claim("Surname", entity.LastName));
             await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(entity, new Claim("NameIdentifier", entity.UserName));

             string roleName = await (from r in _context.AspNetRoles
                                      where r.Id == model.RoleId
                                      select r.RoleName).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
             await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(entity, roleName);
             await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(entity, new Claim("Role", roleName));
             await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

             retUserId = newUserId;
         }
         else
         {
             foreach (IdentityError err in result.Errors)
             {
                 _logger.LogError(3, "userId: " + newUserId.ToString() + " " + err.Code + " - " + err.Description);
             }
         }
     }                                                                                                                                                      

     return retUserId;
 }


Could you clarify the problem you're encountering with the link provided in the exception message? This issue is a known breaking change. EF Core is unable to use the OUTPUT clause to retrieve generated values from tables that have triggers. Instead, it has to resort to other, less efficient techniques. To handle this, EF Core needs you to explicitly indicate that the table has a trigger so that it can use a less efficient SQL query.

I have edited my post above to add the DBContext.cs code which has the OnModelCreateing(modelbuilder) But still I am not able to move forward. It doesn't show the error but doesn't do anything and stops the application.

run in debug and analyse Debug output, it should show exception.

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: 'Could not save changes because the target table has database triggers. SqlException: The target table 'AspNetUsers' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause.

So, why you have put HasTrigger to the wrong entity? You should configure ApplicationUser<int>.

modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable(tb => tb.HasTrigger("TriggerName"));

Also note that you should use the actual trigger name, not TriggerName (which is just an example given by the docs), unless you actually did name your trigger TriggerName...

I think I donot have any triggers created here but still getting this error, so EF will revert to the previous, less efficient technique.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv I also have ApplicationUserClaim,                                                                      ApplicationUserRole,                                                                       ApplicationUserLogin,                                                                       ApplicationRoleClaim,                                                                      ApplicationUserToken> Do I have to write "HasTrigger" statement for all of them?

You have to set HasTrigger to each Entity Class, which has trigger. If you use generic classes as a storage, set it to them.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv I have almost 500 tables in my application. How do I go about adding 500 lines of "HasTrigger". Is there any other approach for adding to so many tables? Also in the SQL Server Management studio, Programmablitiy option, I don't see any triggers in the "Database Triggers" folder. I think there are not triggers created on my tables.

Actually it is easy. I can post code. Do you have some Datbase change tracking library? They useually create truggers automatically.

No, I don't have Database change tracking library. Can you help me with the code please?

@SvyatoslavDanyliv could you help me here with code or some pointers?

modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser<int>>().ToTable(tb => tb.HasTrigger("TriggerName")); - this code is present? Log generated SQL.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv - modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser<int>>().ToTable(tb => tb.HasTrigger("TriggerName")); - Yes I have this code in  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) in DBContext.cs file- Also in another file called, HRISDBcontext.cs I have 100 other entities which is giving the same error for AspNetUserClaim table.

Show definition of your table, show generated SQL.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv I am not able to post code here because of character limitation. **I can do it in my same question same post above  Please see my edited question with the code in it. **

Edit original quetion and post generated SQL.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv please see my edited question above with the new code. It starts with Below is my generated SQL

'_context.AspNetUserClaims.Update(claimFname);' remove Update in other places also. EF tracks changes automatically. SQL is still missing. Which table fails? I see a lot of SaveChanges

@SvyatoslavDanyliv I figured out the line which was throwing the error await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(entity, new Claim("GivenName", entity.FirstName));  I had missed writing modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserClaim<int>>().ToTable(tb => tb.HasTrigger("TriggerName")); My error is resolved. Do I need to write this HasTrigger line for the other 100 entities as well?

If they do not fail, I see no reason. Anyway I can prepare extension method which will set HasTrigger for all entities.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv Can you show me how to prepare extension method to set HasTrigger for all enitites or can you post the method here, please?

@AartiKarnik-OIT, added answer with such extension.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv I will test this out and let you know. Thankyou for posting this.

If you have multiple tables with triggers, you can simplify your code by creating an extension that automatically applies HasTrigger to all entities.
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    
     // Configure all entities
     ...

     // Automatically apply HasTrigger to all entities
     modelBuilder.ApplyHasTrigger();
}

Here’s the implementation of the extension method:
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
    public static ModelBuilder ApplyHasTrigger(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            var tableName = entityType.GetTableName();
            if (tableName != null)
            {
                entityType.AddTrigger("fake_trigger_" + tableName);
            }
        }

        return modelBuilder;
    }
}


This is by design in newer versions of EF Core. See the documentation page SQL Server tables with triggers or certain computed columns now require special EF Core configuration that the error message itself links you to:

Old behavior
Previous versions of the SQL Server provider saved changes via a less efficient technique which always worked.
New behavior
By default, EF Core now saves changes via a significantly more efficient technique; unfortunately, this technique is not supported on SQL Server if the target table has database triggers, or certain types of computed columns. See the SQL Server documentation for more details.
[...]
Mitigations
Starting with EF Core 8.0, the use or not of the "OUTPUT" clause can be configured explicitly. For example:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
       .ToTable(tb => tb.UseSqlOutputClause(false));
}

In EF7 or later, If the target table has a trigger, then you can let EF Core know this, and EF will revert to the previous, less efficient technique. This can be done by configuring the corresponding entity type as follows:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
       .ToTable(tb => tb.HasTrigger("SomeTrigger"));
}

Note that doing this doesn't actually make EF Core create or manage the trigger in any way - it currently only informs EF Core that triggers are present on the table. As a result, any trigger name can be used. Specifying a trigger can be used to revert the old behavior even if there isn't actually a trigger in the table.

(bold emphasis mine)
Read further on that page to see a code example for opting out of the newer technique for all model tables rather relying on per-table mitigation.
Related: SQL Server: Optimize SQL Server OUTPUT clause usage when retrieving database-generated values #27372 - an early GitHub bug report on the issue
Related: SaveChanges, database triggers and unsupported computed columns - the Microsoft Documentation page covering miscellaneous notes for SQL Server

N.B. I do find it rather ironic of the development team to call the new technique "more efficient" when it reliably breaks, while simultaneously acknowledging that the old technique never broke.

I have edited my post above to add the DBContext.cs code which has the OnModelCreateing(modelbuilder) But still I am not able to move forward. It doesn't show the error but doesn't do anything and stops the application.

I am running into a similar issue, but like the OP above, our code does have 'HasTrigger' entries, seems like there may be something else going on?

@awdorrin OP's issue above was that the did not apply the mitigation code, and then when they did assign it, did so to the wrong entity. Please post another question with your own code (including the error you get when debugging) if you have followed the instructions in the documentation as I've copied here and you're still having an error.

My issue turned out to be a bad git merge.
Our local code worked fine, but the pull request didn't pull in the .HasTrigger code.
My advice is: double check your source, don't trust git. :-)
